# media file uploaded is broken but successful response from Facebook Graph

Tags: php, facebook-graph-api, php-curl

I am using the following simple code to upload a file to Facebook Graph. I am success retriving the data from the API but any media file uploaded is broken and I confirm it when I go to see on the template directly on https://business.facebook.com/.

So, If I upload a media file to the template direcly from https://business.facebook.com/ I can retrive all data as the same way am I mentioned but in this case the file is loading and showing perfectly.

```
public function upload_file_fb($token,$archivo,$sesion)
    {        

        $ch = curl_init();
        $url = 'https://graph.facebook.com/v18.0/'.$sesion;

        $data = array(
            'file' => '@'.realpath($archivo)
        );
        $headers = array(); 
        
        $headers[] = 'Authorization: OAuth ' . $token ;
        $headers[] = 'File_offset: 0';

        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 0);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION, CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1);
        
        $result = curl_exec($ch);        

        if($result === false) {
            $result = curl_error($ch) . " - ".curl_errno($ch);
            //return false;
            
        }else{
            $resultDecode = json_decode($result);
            if($resultDecode!=null){
                $result = $resultDecode;
            }
            return($result);
            //return true;
        }
        curl_close($ch);
    }
```

**$archivo="/home/user/public_html/file.jpg"**

*Devel console:*

```
 "response_template": { // response from meta attempt created a media whatsapp template which is created perfectly but with media file broken
        "id": "37.....",
        "status": "PENDING",
        "category": "MARKETING"
    },
    "response_wa": { // response from previous function to get uploaded id
        "id": "upload:MT..."
    },
    "response_wa2": { // response from upload_file_fb();
        "h": "4::aW1..."
    },
```

As you see I am able to get upload id and media id (I am hidden leaf characters with "..." for privacy).

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks experts!

[EDIT]
I post the function to get the upload id.

```
public function meta_upload_media($token,$length,$type)
    {        

        $ch = curl_init();
        $url = 'https://graph.facebook.com/v18.0/886897546187050/uploads';
        
        $data = array(
            'file_length' => $length,
            'file_type' => $type
        );
        $headers = array(); 
        
        $headers[] = 'Authorization: Bearer ' . $token ;
        $headers[] = 'Content-Type:application/json' ;

        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode($data));
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
        
        $result = curl_exec($ch);        

        if($result === false) {
            $result = curl_error($ch) . " - ".curl_errno($ch);
            //return false;
            
        }else{
            $resultDecode = json_decode($result);
            if($resultDecode!=null){
                $result = $resultDecode;
            }
            return($result);
            //return true;
        }
        curl_close($ch);
    }
```

For more details, the file is previously uploaded using upload function of CI4. I can confirm 100% sure that the file is successfully uploaded